# Coefficients of expression $(5x+12x^2+15x^3+8x^4)^{15}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expression $(5x+12x^2+15x^3+8x^4)^{15}$

Comment: Apply multinomial expansion and group terms.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the polynomial with the lowest degree is $5x$, which has a degree of $1$. Since this is multiplied by itself $15$ times, does a coefficient of $x^5$ even exist?